# ag-grid cell rendering error: Cell Renderer must be String or Function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ag-grid

I am working on angular ag-grid.I am trying to use the group cell renderer to display child grid data when clicking on plus sign. while using this, I am getting an error: Cell Renderer must be String or Function.

```
var masterColumnDefs = [
    // group cell renderer needed for expand / collapse icons
    {field: 'name', cellRenderer: 'group'},
    {field: 'account'},
    {field: 'calls'},
    {field: 'minutes', valueFormatter: "x.toLocaleString() + 'm'"}
];

var detailColumnDefs = [
    {field: 'callId'},
    {field: 'direction'},
    {field: 'number'},
    {field: 'duration', valueFormatter: "x.toLocaleString() + 's'"},
    {field: 'switchCode'}
];

var detailGridOptions = {
    columnDefs: detailColumnDefs,
    onGridReady: function(params) {
        params.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
    }
};

var masterGridOptions = {
    columnDefs: masterColumnDefs,
    rowData: rowData,
    masterDetail: true,
    detailCellRendererParams: {
        detailGridOptions: detailGridOptions,
        getDetailRowData: function(params) {
            params.successCallback(params.data.callRecords);
        }
},
onGridReady: function(params) {
    params.api.forEachNode(function (node) {
        node.setExpanded(node.id === "1");
    });
    params.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
}
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var gridDiv = document.querySelector('#myGrid');
    new agGrid.Grid(gridDiv, masterGridOptions);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your name column definition must be like this

```
{field: 'name', cellRenderer:'agGroupCellRenderer'}
```